# I want to play cricket 2002 using wine or play on Linux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I want to play one specific game EA sports Cricket 2002 using wine or play on Linux,This game runs properly only in Windows 98 or Windows XP .Do anyone knows on which particular wine version I can play this game and how to install that version of wine.Which repositories of wine are currently open to play this game.Edit:I am not able to play on current releases of Wine and play on Linux it hangs when i try to run executable 'exe' file,I've tried changing settings using configure wine and winconsole cmd with parameter --nointro.Though I am successful in playing one more game swat3 demo using wine and call of duty?

Comment: "This game runs properly only in Windows 98 or Windows XP and not on other Windows releases" You have no chance, WINE is very hit and miss, mostly only the projects been given priority by the devs will work, think of it like an emulator, though the devs will hate you for it. There is no chance they are looking  for win 98, XP support as it is obsolete and uses an outdated directX 5 , maybe 6, ( This is your issue), my advice, buy a modern game, or install (just look on google) a copy of XP to play your game natively or in a VM.

Comment: @markkirby Most of the games for windows 98 or XP uses DirectX 8

Comment: Direct X 8 may still have support on wine, check your `wine tricks` app (if thats still a thing) Looking on `wine hq`  there is a `d3d8.dll ` and `d3dx8.dll `, see here http://wiki.winehq.org/DirectXStatus Install these the run `wine` in a terminal and try the install again.

Answer (score 0):

Just install latest wine release from official repositories, it will be able to run it without any problems.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I would recommend using wine only since it is more than sufficient to run that game, `playonlinux` is only useful when you want to install multiple versions of wine or set specific `wineprefixes` for different programs. However if you still want to use `playonlinux` you cant install it using

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

The gui of playonlinux is self explanatory just follow installation wizard, it will ask you to select version of wine you want to use and you can download it at that moment.

Comment: Thanks for answer I am not able to play using current release.

Comment: Is it supported by wine, check for your game in wine app database. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true. Also do tell me what is the problem you are encountering, are you not able to run setup?

Comment: I don't know how to search in appdb.

Comment: Here are the results for "cricket" on AppDB, non are your game, time to update I think. https://www.winehq.org/search?q=cricket